# What does "/*+ */" indicate in an Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

What does the symbol `/*+ */` specify in

```
SELECT /*+SU_QW(@MUN$4) */ from Z
```

Comment: You need to read this first before posting a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, well my response was to the other response to Bob Jarvis, now I see all responses are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

`/*+` or `--+` are modified comments which specifically pass hints to Oracle, in order to direct the query optimizer to use one or another strategy. See this entry in the [SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51090). However, I've never heard of a SU_QW hint and can't find anything like that in the SQL Reference or on Google, so I can't tell you what this hint is supposed to do.

Share and enjoy.